# Liquibase generateChangeLog command generates No Change Sets

Tags: liquibase

Following [these](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/existing_project.html) instructions, executing a generateChangeLog command on my existing PostgreSQL database, the resulting file contains no changeset tags. Maybe I misunderstood something, but I thought the modifications to the database up to this point (tables created, etc.) would be already summed up here, and this was the point of the "Make It Look Like You've Always Been Using Liquibase" option.

If this is not a correct assumption, and going forward if I make a modification directly to the database that I want to be described as a changeSet, how do I use the Liquibase command line to add these changesets to the file?

EDIT:

Here is an example of stepping through generateChangeLog and update:

```
./liquibase --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --classpath=postgresql-42.2.4.jar --changeLogFile=changelog1.xml --url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_database" --username=postgres --password=postgres --logLevel=debug generateChangeLog
```

Output:

> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:15 PM: liquibase: Connected to postgres@jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_database
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:15 PM: liquibase: Setting auto-commit to false from true
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:15 PM: liquibase: Computed checksum for 1532117738554 as 2d79fcfb744a18b475eac6c1d1bd804d
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:15 PM: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: SELECT c.relname AS SEQUENCE_NAME FROM pg_class c join pg_namespace on c.relnamespace = pg_namespace.oid WHERE c.relkind='S' AND nspname = 'public' AND c.oid not in (select d.objid FROM pg_depend d where d.refobjsubid > 0)
>
> INFO 7/20/18 8:15 PM: liquibase: changelog1.xml does not exist, creating
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:15 PM: liquibase: MissingObjectChangeGenerator type order:     liquibase.structure.core.Catalog    liquibase.structure.core.Schema    liquibase.structure.core.Sequence    liquibase.structure.core.StoredProcedure    liquibase.structure.core.Table    liquibase.structure.core.Column    liquibase.structure.core.PrimaryKey    liquibase.structure.core.UniqueConstraint    liquibase.structure.core.Index    liquibase.structure.core.ForeignKey    liquibase.structure.core.View
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:15 PM: liquibase: UnexpectedObjectChangeGenerator type order:     liquibase.structure.core.Catalog    liquibase.structure.core.ForeignKey    liquibase.structure.core.Schema    liquibase.structure.core.StoredProcedure    liquibase.structure.core.UniqueConstraint    liquibase.structure.core.View    liquibase.structure.core.Table    liquibase.structure.core.PrimaryKey    liquibase.structure.core.Column    liquibase.structure.core.Index    liquibase.structure.core.Sequence
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:15 PM: liquibase: ChangedObjectChangeGenerator type order:     liquibase.structure.core.Catalog    liquibase.structure.core.ForeignKey    liquibase.structure.core.Schema    liquibase.structure.core.Sequence    liquibase.structure.core.StoredProcedure    liquibase.structure.core.Table    liquibase.structure.core.Column    liquibase.structure.core.PrimaryKey    liquibase.structure.core.UniqueConstraint    liquibase.structure.core.Index    liquibase.structure.core.View
>   Liquibase 'generateChangeLog' Successful

At this point in my local PostgreSQL server, my_database has 2 schemas, one named my_schema (containing 11 tables populated with data that my application is using) and the other named public. The public has no tables.

Running liquibase update:

```
./liquibase --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --classpath=postgresql-42.2.4.jar --changeLogFile=changelog1.xml --url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_database" --username=postgres --password=postgres --logLevel=debug update
```

Returns:

> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Connected to postgres@jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_database
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Setting auto-commit to false from true
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: select count(*) from public.databasechangeloglock
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Create Database Lock Table
>   DEBUG 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Executing EXECUTE database command: CREATE TABLE public.databasechangeloglock (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID))
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Created database lock table with name: public.databasechangeloglock
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: select count(*) from public.databasechangeloglock
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Initialize Database Lock Table
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Executing EXECUTE database command: DELETE FROM public.databasechangeloglock
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Executing EXECUTE database command: INSERT INTO public.databasechangeloglock (ID, LOCKED) VALUES (1, FALSE)
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: SELECT LOCKED FROM public.databasechangeloglock WHERE ID=1
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Lock Database
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Executing UPDATE database command: UPDATE public.databasechangeloglock SET LOCKED = TRUE, LOCKEDBY = '10.0.2.15 (10.0.2.15)', LOCKGRANTED = '2018-07-20 20:21:26.650' WHERE ID = 1 AND LOCKED = FALSE
>   INFO 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Resolving XML entity name='null', publicId='null', baseURI='null', systemId='http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd'
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Opening jar:file:/home/vagrant/Documents/liquibase.jar!/liquibase/parser/core/xml/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd as liquibase/parser/core/xml/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Computed checksum for 1532118089029 as cfbe2a0b147c646104f738103a68b2fd
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Create Database Change Log Table
>
> INFO 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Creating database history table with name: public.databasechangelog
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Executing EXECUTE database command: CREATE TABLE public.databasechangelog (ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, AUTHOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, FILENAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, DATEEXECUTED TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL, ORDEREXECUTED INT NOT NULL, EXECTYPE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, MD5SUM VARCHAR(35), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255), COMMENTS VARCHAR(255), TAG VARCHAR(255), LIQUIBASE VARCHAR(20), CONTEXTS VARCHAR(255), LABELS VARCHAR(255), DEPLOYMENT_ID VARCHAR(10))
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: select count(*) from public.databasechangelog
>
> INFO 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Reading from public.databasechangelog
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: SELECT * FROM public.databasechangelog ORDER BY DATEEXECUTED ASC, ORDEREXECUTED ASC
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: select count(*) from public.databasechangeloglock
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Release Database Lock
>
> DEBUG 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Executing UPDATE database command: UPDATE 
>   public.databasechangeloglock SET LOCKED = FALSE, LOCKEDBY = NULL, LOCKGRANTED = NULL WHERE ID = 1
>
> INFO 7/20/18 8:21 PM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
>
> Liquibase Update Successful

Now under the Public schema, there are 2 tables, databasechangelog, and databasechangeloglock. databasechangelog is empty, but databasechangeloglock contains one row with id 1 and "locked boolean" col "FALSE".

Comment: The assumption is correct. The `generateChangeLog` command should result in a changeset file that contains all "changes" to create your existing DB. If it's empty something is wrong.

Comment: Have you run the command multiple times? If so, then you may need to clear out the changeling tables in order to get a clean result.

Comment: After running the command the first time, I didn't even see new tables being created. I ran a few times after that to no avail.

Comment: Actually, I see the tables were created in a different schema. I'll clear out and try again.

Comment: generateChangeLog generates a file with no changeset elements. Then update creates a databasechangelog and databasechangeloglock table. The databasechangelog table has no entries.

Comment: Most likely you have something slightly mis-configured. Can you update your question with the actual command you used. When running the command, include `--logLevel=debug`. After doing that, add the output to the question also.

Comment: @SteveDonie I just updated my question with the commands and output of stepping through a generateChangeLog and update on an existing postgresql db for the first time.

Comment: Related issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58462643/liquibase-generating-change-logs

Answer (score 3):

I realized I was not specifying the correct schema. I have 2 in the database example, "public" and "my_schema" and Liquibase apparently defaults to the public schema.

The change sets are successfully generated after using the following:

```
./liquibase --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --classpath=postgresql-42.2.4.jar --changeLogFile=changelog.xml --url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_database?currentSchema=my_schema" --username=postgres --password=postgres --liquibaseSchemaName=my_schema generateChangeLog
```

Comment: This answer was successful for me. I needed to run a command for each schema. Without changing the changelog file, liquibase automatically appends to one that is there.